# Using OPA Gatekeeper Mutating Webhooks to remove a sidecar container

Tags: kubernetes, opa, opa-gatekeeper

We have a third-party component we install in our cluster, which (after a series of hoops irrelevant to this question have been jumped through) creates `StatefulSet`s. These `StatefulSet`s are configured with manifests bundled with the product, which we have no control over.

By default, these `StatefulSet`s include a sidecar container which we don't want to run. I'm trying to figure out how to create a Gatekeeper webhook configuration that will mutate the pods created by this `StatefulSet` and remove the sidecar, but I can't figure out the specifics of how to set that up. I *think* what I need is a [`ModifySet`](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/mutation/#modifyset), but the documentation doesn't quite cover this use case.

I tried the following configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: ModifySet
metadata:
  name: first-attempt
spec:
  applyTo:
    - groups: ['']
      versions: ['v1']
      kinds: ['Pod']
  match:
    scope: Namespaced
    namespaces:
      - testing-mutating-webhooks
    kinds:
      - kinds:
        - Pod
  location: 'spec.containers[name: sidecar]'
  parameters:
    operation: prune
```

but that failed to apply with an error `final node in a modifyset location cannot be a keyed list`. So, then I tried changing `location` to just `spec.containers`, but then it's not clear to me what to put in `parameters.value` in order to make it delete the element specified by `name: sidecar`.

I realize this might also be possible using a plain `Assign` mutation, but then I can't instead figure out what to set `parameters.assign.value` to - even if I explicitly set it to `null`, applying it to the cluster fails with an error that I must set `value`, `fromMetadata` or `externalData` (i.e. it does not understand I'm trying to unset the value).

Is it possible to use Gatekeeper mutations to remove a container from a pod? How?